# Regular expression filter out comma and space

Tags: c#

I have a regular expression showed below:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9/ -]");
```

This regular expression filter any alphabet and numbers. However, what I want is I also want to filter out space and comma (,). I am not sure how I add it in there, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your regex is invalid, you need to escape the `/` like this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[[a-zA-Z0-9\/-]");
```

To filter `space` and `,` you can try something like this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9\s,\/-]*");
```

I have added `\s` for space, `,` for comma and `*` for `0 to unlimited matches`. if you want to just match the first instance, you can remove the `*`

Side note, a good place to test regular expressions can be found [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, it has an error :Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: without the `@` sign, .net will try to escape the string before it is passed as a regex.